# Main results in representation theory that are useful in geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, representation-theory

I will take a graduate course in Algebra, which will cover Galois theory, modules and representation theory. If I understand correctly, representation theory helps in the study of groups. Groups arise naturally in geometry (homotopy and homology groups, deck of covering spaces, Lie groups ecc...). My question is: what are the main results in geometry that come from representation theory?

Comment: My experience is that the information usually flows in the other direction. Geometry informs representation theory, not the other way around.